# Invert text selection from DIV

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have several `div` elements like this:

```
<div class="newsContainer">
    <div class="deleteBoxIcon">
        <img alt="Delete" src="close_mark.png">
    </div>
    <div class="newsImage">
        <img alt="NewsImage" src="umbrella.png">
    </div>
    <div class="newsContent">
        <b>Here goes a title</b><br>
        Here goes some content.
    </div>
</div>
```

Based on certain conditions, I retrieve one of those divs and save it into an object (`draggable`), now I need to extract the title and content texts to input controls.

Getting the title is not difficult for me, I'm just doing this:

```
var title = $('.newsContent > b', $(draggable)).text();
```

But the hard part for me is getting the content, I've tried this but it's **not working** because it retrieves all the text (including the title):

```
var content = $(':not(.newsContent > b)', $(draggable)).text();
```

Hope you can help me to get only the content part of a div like this.

Comment: Which part do you want ? can you add some info to your question to show the desired result ...

Comment: Why don't you wrap the content in `<p>` Tags? and the Title in `h1` or any other Heading tag? Then you could get them individually and it would be a more logical markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var title = $('.newsContent > b').text();
var content = $.trim($('.newsContent').text().replace(title, ""));
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Vnhz5/2/)

Comment: Why wouldn't you just get the text that you want directly from the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the last bit of text:

```
$('.newsContent', draggable).contents().last()[0].data;
```

---

- `.contents()` method gives you all child nodes, including text nodes
- `.last()` gives you the last node, which is the one you want
- `[0]` extracts the text node from the jQuery object
- `.data` gives you the text content of the node

---

Or you could replace `[0].data` with `.text()`.

```
$('.newsContent', draggable).contents().last().text();
```

Comment: Can you please explain this -> `$('.newsContent', draggable)` does the comma mean or ?

Comment: @ManseUK: It is setting the context from which `.newsContent` should be searched. It is identical to `$(draggable).find('.newsContent')` (though slightly slower).

Comment: @RightSaidFred thanks for the explanation - struggling to find it on the jQuery selectors doc site ... thanks again

Comment: @ManseUK: You're welcome. You won't find it among the selectors. It is passing a second argument to the `$` function, so you'll [see it here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/). `jQuery( selector [ , context ]  )`. EDIT: I see you already found it! :)

Comment: @RightSaidFred jQuery just keeps giving.... been using it for about 10 months and still sooooo much to learn !

Comment: @lidermin: IMO, you shouldn't use string manipulation to get what you want, when you can just get it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your markup to make writing your JavaScript easier.  Wrap your markup, excluding the heading within another tag, and then select it.

Example:

```
<div class="newsContent">
    <h2>Here goes a title</h2>
    <div class="newsDesc">
        <p>Here goes some content.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, use `$('.newsContent .newsDesc', $(draggable)).text();`